# Why I'm not being able to submit my data to my database using JQuery and PHP and why my page keeps redirecting to the home page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've written the following code to retrieve the data from the HTML form to save it to database using Jquery and AJAX to my SQL database with PHP at the backend. But it constantly redirects to homepage without doing anything.Another thing that I'd like to mention is the form is loaded on click to a button by jquery load() function. I'm really new with JQuery,PHP and AJAX kindly consider that and a simple answer will be really appreciated.

```js
$("#form1").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#dname").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var number = $("#num").val();
  var group = $("#grp").val();
  var location = $("#loc").val();
  var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email='+ email +'&number=' +number +'&group='+ group + '&location='+ location;
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "formsubmit.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result){
    alert(result);
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
   

 <form id="form1" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
     <div class="container">
       <label><b>Name</b></label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" id="dname" required="required"/>
       <br>
       <label><b>Email</b></label>
       <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>
       <br>
       <div id="checkmobile">
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="cbx"> Share my mobile number
       </div>
       <br>
       <div id="mobile">
         <label><b>Mobile number/Contact information</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a 10 digit valid mobile number" id="num" name="number"/>
       </div>
       <div id="group" name="group">
         <label><b>Select a Blood Group :</b></label>
         <select name="group" id="grp" required>
          <option value="A+">A+</option>
          <option value="A-">A-</option>
       <option value="B+">B+</option>
          <option value="B-">B-</option>
          <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
          <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
          <option value="O+">O+</option>
          <option value="O-">O-</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <label><b>Select a Location : ( Incase you're not finding the exact town/village , choose the nearest city )</b></label>
         <select name="location" id="loc" required>
          <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
          <option value="Asansol">Asansol</option>
         </select>
            </div>
        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
        <div class="clearfix">
         <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
         <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" id="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>

the formsubmit.php file

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost"); // Establishing Connection with Server..
if(!$connection)
 die("Error connecting Database!");
$db = mysql_select_db("donor", $connection); // Selecting Database
if(!$db)
 die("Error Connecting Database");
//Fetching Values from URL
$name=sanitize($_POST['name']);
$mail=sanitize($_POST['email']);
$no=sanitize($_POST['number']);
$location=sanitize($_POST['location']);
$group=sanitize($_POST['group']);
//Insert query
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tabledonor (Name,Email,Contact,Location,Blood Group) VALUES ($name,$mail,$no,$location,$group)');
if(query)
 echo "Donor Information Submitted Succesfully";
else
 echo "Error Submitting Informations";
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed

function sanitize($string) {
    return stripslashes(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($string)));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

As far as i know if ur send post data must be a object,
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#dname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var number = $("#num").val();
        var group = $("#grp").val();
        var location = $("#loc").val();
        var dataobj = {
         'name' : name , 
         'email' : email ,
         'number' number  ,
         'group' : group ,
         'location' : location
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "formsubmit.php",
            data: dataobj,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```